# char *data = "abc"; free( (void*)data ); Why void* conversion? Is it necessary?

Tags: c++, c

There is a C-style string and I need to free the memory of it. I saw the following code sample but got confused about why `(void*)` is there.

```
char *data = "abc";
free( (void*)data );
```

Just two questions:

1. Why not simply `free(data)`?
2. Is `(void*)` conversion is a must?

Many thanks.

Comment: This is not right anyways. Don´t free fixed literals.

Comment: (and no, the conversion is not necessary in the free part)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not necessary; the `free()` call is wrong and you cannot do this.

The cast is a huge blinking, bouncing, and screaming warning flag that the originating programmer was confused.

It's undefined behavior to pass a pointer not returned by a previous call to `malloc()` or one of its friends to `free()`. The cast is the least of the problems here.

You can never "free" the memory used by a string literal, since that memory is never allocated in some way that the program controls. It's not on the heap, and the heap is where dynamic memory allocation/deallocation typically happens. Your intention is wrong.

All you can do is set the pointer to `NULL`:

```
data = NULL;
```

that will not in any way "free" the memory used behind the scenes to hold the character data `"abc"` though, but that's fine.

Answer (score 3):

Is an error to call `free()` since is not allocated using `(m/c/re)alloc`.

As pointed out by Jens Gustedt, a cast is only needed when you pass a `const` pointer because `free()` takes a `void *`, not a `const void *`:

```
const int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));

free((void *)x);
```

Without a cast you get:

```
demo.c:8:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘free’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default] In file included from demo.c:2:0: /usr/include/stdlib.h:488:13: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘const int *’
```

Comment: That's ambiguous. It's not necessary *to cast* because it wasn't allocated dynamically?

Comment: Never necessary is not true, unfortunately. If you have a pointer to `const`, many compilers complain.

Comment: This is far too weak a statement. "It is not necessary to call `free()`. No! It is a glaring error to call `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

The cast is unnecessary. In C, a `void*` is implicitly convertible to and from other pointer types. `free` expects a `void*`, so no cast is required from another pointer type.

*(Of course, as already pointed out, the code is obviously problematic altogether, so don't read into it too much.)*

Answer (score 0):

So, your premise here is incorrect, you do not need to free your "data" at all, it will most likely cause a crash if you do. You should only call `free` for data that has come from `malloc`, and `"abc"` is not one of those.

Second, if you are using C, then you should do:

```
char *data = malloc(4);
strcpy(data, "abc");
...
free(data);
```

In C++ we  also can't convert a `void *` [the return value from `malloc`] to `char *`, so you would need `char *data = (char *) malloc(4);`, but `free(data)` should still work. Some compilers may issue warnings for this, and the standard MISRA, for example, does not allow ANY automatic conversions of C types, so explicit casts are REQUIRED here [not because the language says so, but because the MISRA standard does, and there are "checking software" that reads the source code to check these sort of criteria are met].

Of course, in "fresh"[1] C++, we should not use `malloc` or `free`, but `new` and `delete`:

```
char *data = new char[4];
strcpy(data, "abc");
....
delete [] data;
```

[1] As in "code written as C++ from scratch".